# Android wear handled device offline

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working since a few days on an app for my wearable device but since yesterday, i see my device offline.

[image]

my graddle file looks like that :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ile14017.moto360"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
}
```

I tried to reset my handled device, that didn't change anything. It could be coming from my sdk tools (wrong version used?).

Answer (score 0):

your gradle - File is not related to your device state. What get's displayed in your IDE is basically the output of the adb (Android Debug Bridge). So the display of your devices in the IDE is the output of adb list devices.  You could restart the adb by using  
adb kill-server  
adb start-server 
Also you can use adb list devices to see if your device is mentioned where.
As I am not into wearables I don't know if you got to turn on development options there again. On some systems it's importend that the USB vendor id is known, e.g. Linux (udev).

Comment: I enabled debug on the watch and the phone, and I already tried the adb kill-server and start-server commands, without success. Devices stays offline

Comment: so which OS are you using?

Comment: When it happens for me (on Mac or Linux, I don't have a windows box), I often pull the usb cable and reconnect and it goes away. In your case, do you see other devices having the same issue or it is just your wearable device? Also, you may want to make sure there is no lingering adb process around, kill all of them (using whatever is available on windows) to make sure there is no zombie adb processes. If no change, consider rebooting your machine and your wearable device as well.

Comment: I tried everything : killing the processes and restarting, I rebooted everything, disconnected and tried on every usb port of my pc, I even reinitiated the watch but still have the same issue, this is driving me crazy

Comment: Now I have something weird : in the parameters of my android wear, I see both host and target connected but when I build my app, the android watch is still shown offline